# Users that View pages 5 times

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have a number of different product pages and i'm interested in seeing how many users view each product more than 5 times.  I understand I can do this for one of them with a segment and sequence, but I have too many pages that i'm interested in tracking.  Could I do this with a custom metric?  Maybe a calculated metric in analytics or data studio?

Answer (score 0):

there's no reasonable way to do that because Google Analytics metrics are reported in an aggregated way and there's no way to introduce some custom conditions like 'if metric X is greater than N for specific user' other than segments.
the only way is to implement custom tracking that would watch for the number of page views for a particular page/product and then send data to analytics when a specific number of page views is reached.